# A formula to return Table Name by providing the Sheet name and Cell address

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Can anyone help me?

Excel file has 20 sheets

Each sheet has multiple tables

On a new sheet,

Type Sheet Name in Cell A1 - e.g. NorthSales

Type Cell address in Cell A2 e.g. H484

Cell A3 formula should return name of table in sheet Northsales that has cell H484 in it

THANK YOU!!

Comment: This is probably easier to do with VBA.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following User Defined Function:

```
Public Function GetListObject(sh As String, addy As String) As String
    Dim rng As Range, rngLO As Range, LO As ListObject
    Dim msg As String
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    Set sht = Sheets(sh)
    Set rng = sht.Range(addy)

    If sht.ListObjects.Count = 0 Then
        GetListObject = "No ListObjects in sheet " & sh
        Exit Function
    End If

    msg = "cell " & addy & " not in a ListObject"
    For Each LO In sht.ListObjects
        Set rngLO = LO.Range
        If Not Intersect(rng, rngLO) Is Nothing Then
            msg = LO.Name
            Exit For
        End If
    Next LO

    GetListObject = msg
End Function
```

If the sheet referenced has no tables, that is revealed.
If the cell referenced is not in a table, that is revealed.  Otherwise the table name is returned.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer in another post:
[Excel Return Table name using Formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36561623/excel-return-table-name-using-formula)

I used a variation of this solution for my problem:

- I added a formula in each sheet that pointed to a header in the table
- Then I referenced it in my new Sheet and extracted the table name using `FORMULATEXT`, `INDIRECT` and `MID` function

```
      A                          B                                    C                      D
1 SheetName       Formula pointing to each sheet             Extract table Name          Value in cell X2 in each sheet
2 
3 Sheet1       =FORMULATEXT(INDIRECT("'" & A3 &"'!X2"))   =MID(B3,2,FIND("[",B3)-2)  =Status_2022[[#Headers],[Days Open]]
4 Sheet2       =FORMULATEXT(INDIRECT("'" & A4 &"'!X2"))   =MID(B4,2,FIND("[",B4)-2)  =Status_2021[[#Headers],[Days Open]]
5 Sheet3       =FORMULATEXT(INDIRECT("'" & A5 &"'!X2"))   =MID(B5,2,FIND("[",B5)-2)  =Status_2028[[#Headers],[Days Open]]
```

```
</div>
```